# How to use a gerund with 'my' in a sentence?

Tags: gerunds

I am trying to say, "this led to my working as a research assistant with ...". I think something's awry in this phrase. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your (truncated) sentence is perfectly correct. You can (and, according to many style guides, should) use a possessive adjective to modify a gerund.